# Can I restart the computer after ctrl + z?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I have a command that needs to run for a long time.
But I'm going to restart my computer now.
Will it save after <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>?
If it's not possible, is there any way to save？

OS: Ubuntu

Comment: [hibernate doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888933/can-i-use-ctrl-z-to-pause-a-script-and-then-continue-after-rebooting-my-computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> only pauses the process – it doesn't actually store its state anywhere. The process is still in RAM exactly as before, and will be killed during shutdown/reboot like all other processes, the only difference is that it's not given any CPU time while  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>'d.

To actually preserve process state through reboots, a common term is "checkpointing", and this *may* be possible using the [CRIU](https://criu.org/Main_Page) tools on Linux, although in practice it can sometimes fail to resume the process, especially on your first try.

Comment: Is there a safe way in a situation like this?All I know is to use docker to run.

Comment: @zhanzezhu A lot of this depends on what process you're stopping (with ctrl-z).  What are you actually running?

Comment: It is worth noting that at this point the answer is generic to UNIX, and not Linux- or Ubuntu-specific.

Comment: Md5 cracking 

Comment: @chicks: It is not generic to UNIX. There's no CRIU equivalent on Solaris or NetBSD.

Comment: I try to```sudo criu restore -D pause/ -j``` return 
``` 8071: Error (criu/cr-restore.c:1480): 57471 killed by signal 11: Segmentation fault Error (criu/cr-restore.c:2447): Restoring FAILED```